# Impossible to connect to postgres with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, database, postgresql

I'm trying to connect into a postgresSQL database in typescript and to be faire, it doesn't work and it's not explicite why.

I do not have any error log output and so after trying to use manually some `console.log` to debug.

I found that the method connect seem to timeout or fail I don't know since I do not have any logs or other information.

This is what I've done:

```js
import { Client } from 'pg';
import { env } from "./integration.env";
import fs from 'fs';

async function resetDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    const client = new Client(env.database);
    console.log("before connect"); // only output That I got
    await client.connect();
    console.log("after connect"); // not displayed :( 
    const res = await client.query(fs.readFileSync("./seed.sql"), ['Connection to postgres successful!']);
    console.log("connected", res.rows[0].connected); // not displayed :(
    await client.end();
}

resetDatabase().then((a) => console.log("ok", a)).catch(a => console.log("no", a)); // thoses logs are not displayed :(
```

I run this code with the command `npx ts-node test` and the only output I get is `before connect`

It doesn't even display the ok or the no at the end of the promise and so I really don't know where is the problem. If the problem is the data send to the constructor to create the client, I guess the connection method will just fail with a specific error no ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do this with an old version of pg, I updated pg to the version  `8.7.3` and now it works well.

by the way I also added some try catch block because If something fail after the connection it doesn't go to the client.end();

```js
import { Client } from 'pg';
import { env } from "./integration.env";
import fs from 'fs';

async function resetDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    const client = new Client(env.database);
    try {
        console.log("before connect");
        await client.connect();
        console.log("after connect");
        const res = await client.query(fs.readFileSync("./seed.sql"), ['Connection to postgres successful!']);
        console.log("connected", res.rows[0].connected);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    await client.end();
}

resetDatabase().then((a) => console.log("ok", a)).catch(a => console.log("no", a));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be connecting for reasons like the host isn't found but you wouldn't see that because you didn't define a timeout.

In the documentation, the option `connectionTimeoutMillis` of the Client constructor defines the timeout. Its default value is basically infinity.

Add this attribute to your `env.database` or do something like `{ ...env.database, connectionTimeoutMillis: 3000 }` for a timeout of 3 seconds.

If you are using a connection string, you need to do something like this instead:

```js
new Client({
  connectionString: env.database,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 3000,
})
```

More information: https://node-postgres.com/api/client

Comment: To find the real reason of the connection problem, you need to dig. Try connecting to the database using a software like DBeaver. If you can't connect from there, the problem isn't in your code.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips of adding connectionTimeoutMillis now I have some information about a timeout but I tested in a seperated script and my env seem to be working so after testing I saw that I'm not using the latest version of pg and now it work with the correct pg version